# Where would midi cables connect FROM 2 synth wk stations into an interface

Tags: midi, synthesizer, interface

I'm using my Korg Extreme (midi from the OUT) going to midi IN on a Presonus 44VSL interface. This alows me to record using everything about the Korg as it is, or, also as a controller for everything there is in the 'instruments' section of my Studio One 2 DAW. It is quite convenient. 
Is it possible to add another workstation into the mix to act exactly as the first keyboard does? How & where to connect the midi cables- Or the next best scenario?

Answer (score 3):

With a single MIDI input port, the 44VSL can handle only one device.

Nowadays, it is likely that a keyboard has built-in USB. If not, you can use a USB/MIDI interface cable to get a second MIDI IN.

Comment: Remember friend, I'm new at all this. One keyboard has two usb ports, the other keyboard has one. The interface doesnt have a regular usb port. If you are saying the usb ports will resolve my query, could you please tell me where exactly to connect to what?

Comment: @eagerbeginner If your keyboards have USB connection you can connect them directly to your computer, you don't need an interface. Like any other USB device: mouse, printer, scanner, etc. Grab an USB cable and connect one end to your keyboard and the other end to your computer. Repeat with your other keyboard, and you are done.